# IEEE754 FP32/64 standard errors

Tags: floating-point

There's an exercise in my textbook which states:

> Given the IEEE754 FP32/64 standard, indicate the type of error
>   (absolute or relative) that remains constant (motivate briefly the
>   answer possibly with a formula).

The formula is:

Constant relative error:

[image]

I'm finding a hard time in trying to understand what is the exercise talking about. Isn't the absolute error the type of error that remains constant? Can someone clarify it for me?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad question for several reasons, but the author likely wants relative error.

For any fixed inputs and operations, the result is fixed, and so of course any measure of error is fixed. It only makes sense to ask what is constant in the context of something that varies. So the question should say what varies. We can presume they mean that the inputs vary.

It should also say what the relative error is measured relative to. For a single operation, error is often measured relative to the ideal mathematical result. (When there are sequences of operations, errors are affected by intermediate results, and we are sometimes interested in those effects. We will assume the author intends error relative to the ideal mathematical result.)

Neither absolute error nor relative error is completely constant as inputs vary. They are affected by artifacts in the floating-point representation, such they fluctuate in ways similar to adding random noise to calculations. When considering many inputs producing results of similar magnitude, the error varies with bounds of ½ ULP (unit of least precision) (assuming rounding to nearest). It bounces up and down, again somewhat akin to noise. When the output crosses an exponent boundary in the floating-point representation, the fluctuations grow or shrink in proportion.

It is that proportion the author takes as “constant.” Crudely, the relative errors remain within a bound that is constant relative to the magnitude of the ideal mathematical result. They are in fact not constant, but there is a good bound on the errors in a neighborhood that is constant relative to the magnitude (until we reach the high or low limits of magnitude supporting by the floating-point format). In contrast, a similar bound on the absolute errors is not constant; it grows as results grow.

Comment: A bad question for sure. Relative error can be really large in magnitude once one gets into subnormal operands. There, a tiny 1 ulp difference could represent a relative error of 50%.

Comment: @njuffa it's even worse when you overshoot the bounds for exponent in the other direction...